# How more than a one program uses the registers simultaneously without interrupting other programs on the windows OS?

Tags: windows, assembly, operating-system, cpu-registers, context-switch

i've been wondering how multiple programs that run at **the same time** use the CPU registers without causing a conflict between the programs on the Windows OS.

does Windows OS uses a "virtual registers" to avoid such scenario(where multiple programs uses same registers simutaniously) ?

so if for example two programs use the `eax` register does the OS really change the physical `eax` register ?

or it uses some "virtual register" just like i've mentioned above ?

Comment: If you have multiple cores you also have multiple register files. That is the only way multiple programs actually run at the same time. The OS also does multitasking, that is scheduling the cores between threads so it appears they are running at the same time. When the cpu is given to a new thread, the register state of the previous one is saved and the new one loaded. This is called a context switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operating system does not use virtual registers, the physical registers are changed.

In the old days machines only had one CPU core and only one thread was actually running at any point in time. Every time before a different thread can start running the OS kernel will save the state (registers) of the old thread and restore the state of the new thread before it can continue. This is called a context switch. The switch happens in kernel mode and if the thread it is switching to lives in a different process it also has to change the virtual memory mapping.

On a system with multiple cores multiple threads can run at the same time and each core has its own set of registers.

MSDN gives a rough overview of [how context switching works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/context-switches) on Windows:

> The scheduler maintains a queue of executable threads for each
> priority level. These are known as ready threads. When a processor
> becomes available, the system performs a context switch. The steps in
> a context switch are:
>
> - Save the context of the thread that just finished executing.
> - Place the thread that just finished executing at the end of the queue for its priority.
> - Find the highest priority queue that contains ready threads.
> - Remove the thread at the head of the queue, load its context, and execute it.
>
> ...
>
> The most common reasons for a context switch are:
>
> - The time slice has elapsed.
> - A thread with a higher priority has become ready to run.
> - A running thread needs to wait.

If your program is running on a preemptive multitasking OS then you don't have to think about how and why context switches happen, you can just pretend you are always in control of the registers and that your program is the only program running.

Comment: Context-switching is effectively virtualizing the registers, so each task (thread) has its own set of architectural registers.  Just like how virtual memory gives each process its own address-space.  But yeah, we don't call it "virtual registers", we just say "that thread's registers".